# C++ SPDLOG compilation error: variable or field ‘set_error_handler’ declared void

Tags: c++, cmake, spdlog

I'm trying to use spdlog in my project. According to  [spdlog docu](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/1.-QuickStart), I just need to copy files under include folder and use a C++ 11 compiler.

I copied the /include/spdlog folder to my project root folder but I'm having a lot of errors after trying to build the project. Some are the ff:

```
/home/project/Documents/project-server/spdlog/spdlog.h:46:39: error: variable or field ‘set_error_handler’ declared void
void set_error_handler(log_err_handler);
                                   ^
/home/project/Documents/project-server/spdlog/spdlog.h:46:24: error: ‘log_err_handler’ was not declared in this scope
 void set_error_handler(log_err_handler);
                    ^
In file included from /home/project/Documents/project-server/main.cpp:13:0:
/home/project/Documents/project-server/spdlog/spdlog.h:74:79: error: ‘filename_t’ does not name a type
 std::shared_ptr<logger> basic_logger_mt(const std::string& logger_name, const filename_t& filename, bool truncate = false);
                                                                           ^
/home/project/Documents/project-server/spdlog/spdlog.h:75:79: error: ‘filename_t’ does not name a type
 std::shared_ptr<logger> basic_logger_st(const std::string& logger_name, const filename_t& filename, bool truncate = false);
                                                                           ^
/home/project/Documents/project-server/spdlog/spdlog.h:80:82: error: ‘filename_t’ does not name a type
 std::shared_ptr<logger> rotating_logger_mt(const std::string& logger_name, const filename_t& filename, size_t max_file_size, size_t max_files);
```

I have tried adding the following in the CMakeLists.txt

```
target_include_directories(ProjectName INTERFACE spdlog)

include_directories(spdlog)

target_link_libraries(ProjectName .... -libspdlog-dev)
```

(I installed libspdlog-dev)

```
add_subdirectory(spdlog)
```

but none of the above works. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As written in [spdlogs docu at the very bottom](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/9.-CMake), you can do a

```
find_package(spdlog CONFIG)
```

This provides you the imported interface library `spdlog::spdlog`, which you can use

```
target_link_library(my_library PUBLIC spdlog::spdlog)
```

(as seen in the [spdlog/examples/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/master/example/CMakeLists.txt))

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to install spdlog:

```
sudo apt-get install libspdlog-dev
```

and include using:

```
#include <spglog/spdlog.h>
```

I initially just copied spdlog to my project root and was trying to include using:

```
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
```